# Error using hashlib++ in c++ builder?

Tags: c++, encryption, hash, c++builder

I downloaded the latest hashlib++ 0.32 version and tried to use hash functions but it says Unsupported compiler.

```
[BCC32 Fatal Error] hl_types.h(71): F1003 Error directive: "Unsuppported compiler."                "Please use GCC,MINGW,MSVC "            " or define hl_uint64 for your compiler in hl_types.h line 62"
```

The hl_types.h looks

```
/*
 * hashlib++ - a simple hash library for C++
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2010 Benjamin Grьdelbach
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 *  1)     Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 
 *  2)     Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *         the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *         distribution.
 *       
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
 * ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

//----------------------------------------------------------------------    

/**
 *  @file   hl_types.h
 *  @brief  This file defines some global types
 *  @date   So 13 Jan 2008
 */  

//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
//include protection
#ifndef HLTYPES_H
#define HLTYPES_H

//----------------------------------------------------------------------    

/**
 * exactly 1 Byte
 */
typedef unsigned char   hl_uint8;

/**
 * at least 2 Byte
 */
typedef unsigned short int  hl_uint16;

/**
 * at least 4 Byte
 */
typedef unsigned int hl_uint32;

/**
* at least 8 Byte
*/
#ifdef __GNUC__
    typedef unsigned long long int  hl_uint64;
#elif __MINGW32__
    typedef unsigned long long int  hl_uint64;
#elif _MSC_VER
    typedef unsigned __int64 hl_uint64;
#else
    #error "Unsuppported compiler." \
               "Please use GCC,MINGW,MSVC " \
           " or define hl_uint64 for your compiler in hl_types.h line 62"
#endif


//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
//end of include protection
#endif

//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
//EOF
```

I am asking is there any way to make it work in Borland C++ builder 2010 (BCC32) compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message pretty much says what to do... add the following to the header file below the _MSC_VER check and above the final #else:

```
#elif defined( __BORLANDC__ )
typedef unsigned __int64 hl_uint64;
```

(Builder has an "__int64" extended integer type)

Comment: I added the following lines to hl_types
#elif defined( __BORLANDC__ )
typedef unsigned __int64 hl_uint64;

Answer (score 0):

The "Unsupported compiler" error comes from the section of code that says:

```
/**
* at least 8 Byte
*/
#ifdef __GNUC__
    typedef unsigned long long int  hl_uint64;
#elif __MINGW32__
    typedef unsigned long long int  hl_uint64;
#elif _MSC_VER
    typedef unsigned __int64 hl_uint64;
#else
    #error "Unsuppported compiler." \
           "Please use GCC,MINGW,MSVC " \
       " or define hl_uint64 for your compiler in hl_types.h line 62"
#endif
```

You need to learn to read error messages if you're going to do a lot of programming.  Specifically, the part of the message that says "or define hl_uint64 for your compiler in hl_types.h line 62."  All you need to do is add a line that identifies a 64 bit integral type along the lines of the other compilers in that section.  For instance:

```
typedef unsigned long long hl_uint64;
```

Or, if Borland gives you access to stdint.h:

```
#include "stdint.h"
typedef uint64_t hl_uint64;
```